# Print string in php

Tags: php

I am trying to print the following string in php

```
var_dump('RQC7<lzC;_ytr@ewm6Eo');
```

But it only prints `RQC7`. If I remove the character `<`, then I get the complete string. I do not understand why this is happening. I googled but could not find any answer.

I had to use an image because I could not print the total string in stack overflow either.

Actually this is part of a shared secret, which Client codes will access with `$obj->getSharedSecret();` I was just testing the output of the function with `var_dump()`. If var_dump cannot print the total string, then this wont work to validate input, right?

Regards,
TAnvir

Comment: `<` is seen by the browser as the start of an HTML tag! The browser obviously has no idea how to process the `<lxC;...` tag

Comment: Take a look at the page source code, it will all be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, presumably, looking at the output in a web browser.

By default PHP will include a `Content-Type: text/html` response header, so the browser will try to interpret the result as if it were HTML.

In HTML `<` means "Start of tag".

If you want to include `<` as data, you need to use a character reference such as `&lt;` instead.

Use the `htmlspecialchars` function to convert your string of text to a string of HTML.

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars('RQC7<lxC; etc etc');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It because "<" is tag start, its actually printing string you want but you don't see it in your html. You need to take a look to source or use [htmlentities](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) functions. Or if you prefer use var_dump for this kind of printing install [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) (which will transform string into correct string representation)

Answer (score -2):

you can use this

```
htmlentities('RQC7<lxc;_ytr@ewm6Eo');
```

Comment: A good answer will normally tell the questioner WHY this is a good solution